# Printing Range Of ASCII Characters From Registers in x86 Assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, ascii

I'm trying to print a range of ascii characters with this assembly program.
I'm trying to do it using only the registers, but haven't been having much luck. Everything looks fine to me, but I'm a novice at assembly programming and might have missed something obvious. Any insight will be appreciated. Thanks :)

*emphasized text*
    .text
    .global _start

```
_start:
 movl $1, %edx

movl $65, %ebx
start_loop:
 addl $1, %ebx 
 movl $0x04, %eax
 int $0x80
 cmpl $126, %ebx
 jle start_loop 
 jmp start_loop 

 exit
 movl $0, %ebx
 movl $1, %eax
 int $0x80
```

Comment: What is the problem? If it is that your program never stops, it is because your `jle` and `jmp` instructions both go to the start of the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are invoking the sys_write system call. sys_write() takes three arguments, file descriptor of the output device(it should be 1 for stdout),address of the buffer where you stored the value to be printed, and the size of the data to be printed. So you have to store file descriptor in %ebx, and store address of the buffer in %ecx and size of the data in %edx. To store the file descriptor you can use the following instruction.

```
          movl $1, %ebx        // store 1 (stdout) in ebx)
```

To store the size of the data you can use:

```
          movl $1, %edx        // size is 1 byte
```

Now, you have to store the address of the buffer, you need to put your data in the memory some where and need to store the address of the memory in %ecx. Assume that you want store the data in the stack it self, then you can do like this:

```
          subl $4, %esp     // get 4 bytes of memory in the stack
          movl $65, (%esp)  // store data in the memory where esp points to
          movl %esp, %ecx   // store address of the data in the ecx
```

Now you can issue the int 0x80.

```
         movl $04, %eax    // store syscall number in eax    
         int  $0x80       // issue the trap interrupt
```

As a whole you can write the following code:

```
    movl $1, %ebx
    subl $0x4, %esp
    movl $64, (%esp)
    start_loop:
    movl (%esp), %eax
    addl $1, %eax
    movl %eax, (%esp)
    movl %esp, %ecx
    movl $1, %edx
    movl $0x04, %eax
    int $0x80
    movl (%esp), %eax
    cmpl $126, %eax
    jle start_loop
    addl $0x4, %esp
```

See Linux System Calls Part2 at http://www.rulingminds.com/syscallspart2 to know more about registers and system calls usage.

Comment: +1 BTW you need a newline before the code blocks for them to show up properly.

Answer (score 1):

"Thank you very much for the informative answer, but is there a way to store and retrieve the value to be printed in a register without pointing to it?" -- this should probably have been edited into the question.

If you insist on using only syscalls (`int $0x80`) to interface with the system then the answer is no. You have to somehow pass a buffer to `write` and rullingminds answer applies.

Using the libc `putchar(3)` it's straight forward. I use `%ebx` to keep the ascii code as this register is on linux preserved between function calls. Simply assemble using `gcc filename.S` (remembering to use `-m32` if you are on x86_64).

```
.text

.extern putchar

.global main
main:  
    # make room for argument to putchar on the stack
    sub $4, %esp

    # initialize ebx with first value to print
    mov $'A', %ebx
1:
    # give character to print as argument
    mov %ebx, (%esp)
    call putchar

    # move to next character
    inc %ebx

    # are we done?
    cmp $'~', %ebx
    jle 1b

    # print newline
    movl $10, (%esp) 
    call putchar

    # adjust stack back to normal
    add $4, %esp

    # return 0 from main
    mov $0, %eax
    ret
```