# GCC: putchar(char) in inline assembly

Tags: linux, gcc, assembly, x86-64, inline-assembly

Overflow,

how can I implement the putchar(char) procedure using inline assembly only? I would like to do this in x86-64 assembly. The reason for me doing this is to implement my own standard-lib (or at least part of it). Here is what I have so far:

```
void putchar(char c)
{   
    /* your code here: print character c on stdout */
    asm(...);
}   

void _start()
{   
    /* exit system call */
    asm("mov $1,%rax;"
        "xor %rbx,%rbx;"
        "int  $0x80"
    );  
}
```

I am compiling with:

```
gcc -nostdlib -o putchar putchar.c
```

Thanks for helping me!

Comment: What OS/environment? What have you tried so far? You'll have to be more precise than that.

Comment: Thanks for you quick reply, it's Linux on x86-64. I have tried to invoke interrupt 0x80 with %eax, 0x04. But I did not know how to access/forward the function parameter of putchar(char) in/to inline-assembly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048422/printing-range-of-ascii-characters-from-registers-in-x86-assembly

Comment: @dubbaluga - You might also want to consider why [the real putchar](https://github.com/tianocore/edk2/blob/master/StdLib/LibC/Stdio/putchar.c) might not be written in assembly.

Comment: @Mat: The first link does not really provide an answer as it is not inline code. What I really need is a hint on how to forward the content of variables to inline assembly.

Comment: @BoPersson: That's interesting: why isn't it written in assembly? At some point it has to translate to invoking syscalls, or not?

Comment: @dubbaluga: no, at some point, it has to call some code outside the standard library. And it can do that without messing around with assembly. It isn't written in assembly because it doesn't *need* to be written in assembly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using GNU C inline asm, **use constraints to tell the compiler where you want things**, instead of doing it "manually" with instructions inside the asm template.

For `writechar` and `readchar`, we only need a `"syscall"` as the template, with constraints to set up all the inputs in registers (and the pointed-to `char` in memory for [the `write(2)` system call](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html)), according to the x86-64 Linux system-call convention (which very closely matches the System V ABI's function-calling convention).  [What are the calling conventions for UNIX & Linux system calls on i386 and x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535989/what-are-the-calling-conventions-for-unix-linux-system-calls-on-i386-and-x86-6).

This also makes it easy to avoid clobbering the red-zone (128 bytes below RSP), where the compiler might be keeping values.  You must not clobber it from inline asm (so `push` / `pop` aren't usable unless you `sub rsp, 128` first: see [Using base pointer register in C++ inline asm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34520013/using-base-pointer-register-in-c-inline-asm) for that and many useful links about GNU C inline asm), and there's no way to tell the compiler you clobber it.  You could build with `-mno-redzone`, but in this case input/output operands are much better.

---

I'm hesitant to call these `putchar` and `getchar`.  You can do that if you're implementing your own stdio that doesn't support buffering yet, but some functions *require* input buffering to implement correctly.  For example, `scanf` has to examine characters to see if they match the format string, and leave them "unread" if they don't.  Output buffering is optional, though; you *could* I think fully implement stdio with functions that create a private buffer and `write()` it, or directly `write()` their input pointer.

### `writechar()`:

```
int writechar(char my_char)
{
    int retval;  // sys_write uses ssize_t, but we only pass len=1
                 // so the return value is either 1 on success or  -1..-4095 for error
                 // and thus fits in int

    asm volatile("syscall  #dummy arg picked %[dummy]\n"
                    : "=a" (retval)  /* output in EAX */
                    /* inputs: ssize_t read(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count); */
                    : "D"(1),         // RDI = fd=stdout
                      "S"(&my_char),  // RSI = buf
                      "d"(1)          // RDX = length
                      , [dummy]"m" (my_char) // dummy memory input, otherwise compiler doesn't store the arg
                    /* clobbered regs */
                    : "rcx", "r11"  // clobbered by syscall
                );
    // It doesn't matter what addressing mode "m"(my_char) picks,
    // as long as it refers to the same memory as &my_char so the compiler actually does a store

    return retval;
}
```

This compiles very efficiently [with gcc -O3, on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5HhYEA1AHdihTMgRNiEdZvkBbAJ4B9HcQCUHAAwARKwEEOAdj43789/NkLimAgDcmBg4AZh53AHpw%2BUEDQSNlVXkRQUxBaME8AC9MIwJSeQAjEQVFTHlUFgYDeQAHJkE0hkwWEOtaK1tLOw8e3t7I6NR5AgQynwIxFnkAhhEyvDTMQlHieVpyqcERZAkG8tX5AFpaADoTw4AWSwBOAFZ5ADMSeUxiYhIO%2B0%2Bunvq9adQzAIeCaEG4XBigmQgQY7m4wXQIj0hnkmmAtTwyAA1ph0PJuLcOLceIjkQYibZbgBhFpcLjfbp9Jl9ED4umtJjg%2BQQcYzMwRABU5WKNWKnim2DsAA15ALwgzmYqPOEhbJRQRBKyGlkct5MEx0BAvI90Pk0CxBAo/Kg8HiBUUHvkMtlcvI0CI5BZQrL5a4fkrFazwbY6RBaGZ8syBgAlawASXxwWsJtalvQogICoDSvBAGVwWCuAA2QwmDTmSMx3MJ1qFEQPLPZ5ng9AF8NKmPWGW1ppsEaNpt9fJEklIwwU8F6LkQUumfkDUkovSYPQkapq4r5VAjV6KBZlNB6Gog17ydOpFhgKQKS0kMo71HEYADweCt0MVAFAqvXHyHzANI5RfV8gzpcQAA9wWHMDaHaOkIiiZAPy/H88QKapIWhBggj9RlBy9FxOjw%2BQBjjBRz0ES9r30JgCAIU9FA0BQDXQHxtTYfQMDKScC1nct%2BWPbFBFIAcBnqeQPw48TCD/TAHleNIiGGUZoiYZd9BXNdUTSbgS2MUxBmUg9UCPE9ViYZAJhhaoKNRaIiB8BkB3GSZZP8QIQkIr5HE6IiGWNHwDVMCBrVtCxcKcLz/XcALfBmTyBw9DJgBYX8DL4zQEtw35BH%2Ba0gRPQsIViLDYTZBEx2qNEMWxX8CRHRdyVuSkaXBYDBxVYUCHVQDfSI19elA%2Bkk05eCeTiwJwv6gaehE4lGondkkynMaMvMEiono7CjLdEzjyaVYHz%2BM8f3knwWF2Nk9LLTKIuyma3w3DUtWdXVZINI05BNfJQrtB0nR1V13U9TyfXapshpDLgIEsCNFU7GskxTJM01kcHBzzaddLWuGEcTZMHXRpsWzbfl4aiWNuyR3tgH7O7poeoaIKgtkuGIWCuQ299P2/Hw0IwkqYSJvoCIHPAHm5XlAkTKl5Fh5UomOeQziOK47kfMpDleYgWCGGY5kEcGXJ1tz4tCZzfFctbQYQl4GBSOzLDOLhbnuAyonQ%2BinJ8pz6fsY09CYWQQptdApu8qLiPS/Tyyyvz7vcJ5VhnGPdFrK8mCvUG1pl9OpEyLPvWt3h%2BHD6LFQSejgpxuOvgTpQVCr8sICz6kqNF%2BvjamSxa66JxfLr%2BO/K4YJxblhkBgAOWjAAtK80lkOSHkxPBmmYlg0JEYBgGqbRkN5xSVL5zIKkwfk/AUvAKgnqJWDQwKsTSPcRiOQPctaLxMBwojfv0Yx1WCtHG65hvaRx6MadAigSDoGAb3YikDoHAPxtyLwZhrbm3rsdfKtFCrC0VOCE4n8GBGBiHIJg4F5C6xqD4ZekFzZtzavXAak5UB%2BD/LQSwpBiCCBqAlBh8FbaCCYBfP8PCTh4ObHSLYBRRE1FIAADj4a1ARCtoh1AkI8Z4Dozr5ECHgFKhRqjyPEUw18LC2Ejm4bw5qpAPL0OUVwQRDl7wqVMBZeiqwvBDG0a8ExDMZrmJePgUg7R7G0kcT0AYuYAAq1gADyABVaJfi3APVZquNh3C8BcJ4Uo8Jqiag2jkKeJSPjiApPLswukGSgngRCXkzmqjLQqA4jTF%2BshDH0UEBU4iVSuA1P1HU0JfB%2BERNUQAdWjHGaJ2AelpNZphIWYTGmRMQvvBSf5kAUN0uw04EimSBKsVwjhDSVEDDYs42Rcy0kENogQEhBgyEUOoXJPAdCRkOP2X0TqGYepg1MYOEAXz%2BiqhYD1Vkgz/n%2BIGkNUa0MEHEBgXOYFkShRIR5qhWSAEoWpMZqzZmdJoJs3QJBQl%2BKMgs3BIivAlKYI9zJVSjm7IAWKg7n5H2EUR7NHwA2XCUgIwMGkLcKQpAWDSEsCK1A0gqT8H4IMMQGj4S0BFQQcV/KIxYhALcLgJxggjyLPI64XBaDyK4BceRlguCMGkBcEVYqpAStIFKqQIrNScNVQ6/lpA4CwCQIefarxyCUH9WZEAwB5H0GXgwDxmoIAFDVaQAoshNAGGkMq0gh5lxyDiZUVNnrSBYEDmwJoCb8A%2BEsngC%2Bmp82YHAmoYokgpDpqIWmlVKg9CtoFawdgsreCMDwAUTUkAIyoBqMCCo1bDjgWQEcOJwQjhplaClEQsEjjjJhGu2tBBiBMFdaIcQkhwzWqkMK0VCbnXgXkUWQ4RYLjyGADseQxj1gQFwIQZ4Sr8hUj2mZcq7YZUl14CqtVZgNUgAuI4E4RZHBFmCBwxwEbHC3FoNceRx7bWkA7Rwzh9rHXOtdSAd1IGBXSC4Ha890hgOetA6QC%2BWSKjgaAA%3D).

```
writechar:
    movb    %dil, -4(%rsp)        # store my_char into the red-zone
    movl    $1, %edi
    leaq    -4(%rsp), %rsi
    movl    %edi, %edx            # optimize because fd = len
    syscall               # dummy arg picked -4(%rsp)

    ret
```

@nrz's test `main` inlines it *much* more efficiently than the unsafe (red-zone clobbering) version in that answer, taking advantage of the fact that `syscall` leaves most registers unmodified so it can just set them once.

```
main:
    movl    $97, %r8d            # my_char = 'a'
    leaq    -1(%rsp), %rsi       # rsi = &my_char
    movl    $1, %edx             # len
.L6:                           # do {
    movb    %r8b, -1(%rsp)       # store the char into the buffer
    movl    %edx, %edi           # silly compiler doesn't hoist this out of the loop
    syscall  #dummy arg picked -1(%rsp)

    addl    $1, %r8d
    cmpb    $123, %r8b
    jne     .L6                # } while(++my_char < 'z'+1)

    movb    $10, -1(%rsp)
    syscall  #dummy arg picked -1(%rsp)

    xorl    %eax, %eax         # return 0
    ret
```

---

### readchar(), done the same way:

```
int readchar(void)
{
    int retval;
    unsigned char my_char;
    asm volatile("syscall  #dummy arg picked %[dummy]\n"
                    /* outputs */
                    : "=a" (retval)
                     ,[dummy]"=m" (my_char) // tell the compiler the asm dereferences &my_char

                    /* inputs: ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count); */
                    : "D"(0),         // RDI = fd=stdin
                      "S" (&my_char), // RDI = buf
                      "d"(1)          // RDX = length

                    : "rcx", "r11"  // clobbered by syscall
                );
    if (retval < 0)   // -1 .. -4095 are -errno values
        return retval;
    return my_char;   // else a 0..255 char / byte
}
```

Callers can check for error by checking `c < 0`.

Comment: @dubbaluga: GNU C inline asm is hard enough to use without unsafe examples that happen to work for some callers floating around on SO; thanks for accepting this answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example `my_putchar` in GCC x86-64 inline assembly (in Intel syntax, converting to AT&T should be trivial).

Compiles with:

```
gcc -ggdb -masm=intel -o gcc_asm_putchar gcc_asm_putchar.c
```

**Edit:** `rdi` was missing from clobbered registers. Fixed.

Here's the code:

```
int main(void)
{
    char my_char;

    for (my_char = 'a'; my_char <= 'z'; my_char++)
            my_putchar(my_char);

    my_char = '\n';
    my_putchar(my_char);
    return 0;
}

void my_putchar(char my_char)
{
    int dword_char;
    dword_char = (int)my_char;
    asm volatile(
                    ".intel_syntax noprefix;"
                    "mov r10,rsp;"   // save rsp.
                    "sub rsp,8;"     // space for buffer, align by 8.
                    "mov [rsp],al;"  // store the character into buffer.
                    "mov edi,1;"     // STDOUT.
                    "mov rsi,rsp;"   // pointer to buffer.
                    "mov edx,1;"     // string length in bytes.
                    "mov eax,1;"     // WRITE.
                    "syscall;"       // clobbers rcx & r11.
                    "mov rsp,r10;"   // restore rsp.
                    ".att_syntax prefix;"
                    /* outputs */
                    :
                    /* inputs: eax */
                    : "a"(dword_char)
                    /* clobbered regs */
                    : "rcx", "rdx", "rsi", "rdi", "r10", "r11"
                );
}
```

Comment: does not compile for me. :( Says: gcc_asm_putchar.c:36: undefined reference to `rbp'

Comment: `"sub rsp,8;"` is not safe in inline asm; you clobber the red-zone and there's no way to tell the compiler about it.  Use a memory input operand, or `sub rsp, 128`.  [Using base pointer register in C++ inline asm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34520013).  Also, you tell the compiler that `rax` is input-only, but `syscall` clobbers it with the return value.  Also, your code breaks if compiled with `-masm=intel`: you unconditionally leave the assembler in AT&T mode for compiler-generated code.

Answer (score 2):

Note that `getchar(3)`/`putchar(3)` are macros (for performance) which mess around with complex data in the `FILE` structure for `stdin`/`stdout`, specifically handling buffering and other. The answer by nrz just does a 1 char `write(3)` to file descriptor 1, something *very* different.