# Unable to print a number in x86 assembly nasm

Tags: assembly, x86

I want be able to print a number using the following asm program but I am unable to and on running it, I do not get **3** as an expected output, why?

```
section .data
        count equ 3

section .text
        global _start

_start:
        mov eax,4
        mov ebx,1
        mov ecx,count
        mov edx,1
        int 80h

        mov eax,1
        int 80h
```

Comment: The function does not print numbers: it prints an array of characters – text.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>  count equ 3
> ```

Because *count* was defined being an `equ`, *count* in your program represents the value 3 and nothing more.

Now the api call that you use for printing expects in ECX **the address in memory where you have stored the number 3**.
You should use the following that reserves in the .data section room for a byte with the ASCII value for the digit that displays as **3**:

```
section .data
        count db "3"

section .text
        global _start

_start:
        mov eax,4
        mov ebx,1
        mov ecx,count
        mov edx,1
        int 80h

        mov eax,1
        int 80h
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are passing the number 3, not **a pointer to the character "3"**.

This is a link to an ascii table: https://www.asciitable.com/

Here's a similar stack article: [How to print a single ASCII char?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20466018/how-to-print-a-single-ascii-char)