# Writing a putchar in Assembly for x86_64 with 64 bit Linux?

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm, x86-64, system-calls

I am trying to use the write `syscall` in order to reproduce the `putchar` function behavior which prints a single character. My code is as follows,

```
asm_putchar:
  push    rbp
  mov     rbp, rsp

  mov     r8, rdi

call:
  mov     rax, 1
  mov     rdi, 1
  mov     rsi, r8
  mov     rdx, 1
  syscall

return:
  mov     rsp, rbp
  pop     rbp
  ret
```

Comment: Have you verified that `rdi` contains a valid string address? Also, you're running this on a 64-bit Linux system, right?

Comment: Can you write it in C? Note that `putchar` accepts a character but `write` expects a pointer.

Comment: Yes I'm running on a 64-bit Linux, I know that write takes a pointer but most of people using this syscall use a data section to store strings

Comment: Can't you use the stack instead?

Comment: It consists to push rax and use the syscall again ?

Comment: @Lucas Push the desired character on the stack, then pass a pointer to that character to the system call.

Comment: thanks, i'll try that

Comment: Just to be sure, can I use the rbp pointer register (pushed at begining) and move rbp, rdi. And so use rbp instead of r8 in my previous exemple ?

Comment: you don't need additional register. You need memory. Also you don't need to touch `rbp` at all (including push/pop). You can just `push rdi` at the beginning to store the character into the stack (= memory), then `mov rsi,rsp` will get the memory address of stored char into `rsi`. And remember to release the stored character after `sys_write`, like `add rsp,8` (or `pop` into some register which you don't need any more, `pop rcx` is probably good candidate, as `rcx` was modified by `syscall` already).

Comment: Related: [GCC: putchar(char) in inline assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50691215).  See the compiler asm output in my answer for a complete asm function that implements `return sys_write(1, &my_char, 1);`.  On the Godbolt link, you can click the "intel" button to get Intel syntax instead of AT&T.

Comment: Strangely I couldn't find an exact duplicate of this very simple question.  It's been asked and answered many times for the `int 0x80` 32-bit ABI, but possibly not for x86-64.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [`man 2 write`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html), you can see the signature of `write` is,

```
ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count);
```

It takes a pointer (`const void *buf`) to a buffer in memory.  You can't pass it a `char` by value, so you have to store it to memory and pass a pointer.

(Don't `write` one char at a time unless you only have one to print, that's really inefficient, which is why C stdio buffers I/O normally.  Construct a buffer in memory and print that:  e.g. this x86-64 Linux NASM function: [How do I print an integer in Assembly Level Programming without printf from the c library? (itoa, integer to decimal ASCII string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13166064/how-do-i-print-an-integer-in-assembly-level-programming-without-printf-from-the/46301894#46301894))

A NASM version of *[GCC: putchar(char) in inline assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15596688/gcc-putcharchar-in-inline-assembly/50691215#50691215)*, tweaked a bit for code-size / efficiency.

```
; x86-64 System V calling convention: input = byte in DIL
; clobbers: RDI, RSI, RDX,  RCX, R11 (last 2 by syscall itself)
; returns:  RAX = write return value: 1 for success, -1..-4095 for error
writechar:
    lea     rsi, [rsp-4]          ; RSI = buf in the red zone (below RSP)
    mov    [rsi], edi             ; store the char from RDI into it

    mov     eax, 1                ; __NR_write syscall number from unistd_64.h
    mov     edi, 1                ; EDI = fd=1 = stdout
    ; RSI = buf set earlier, before overwriting the char in EDI
    mov     edx, eax              ; RDX = len = 1  happens to be the same as fd and call #
    syscall                    ; rax = write(1, buf, 1)
    ret
```

We actually only need a 1 byte store, like `mov [rsp-1], dil`, but a 4-byte store saves a byte of code-size.  And `int putchar(int)` means the caller should have written a full register, so we aren't going to get a partial-register stall even on old CPUs.

---

If you *do* pass an invalid pointer in RSI, such as `'2'` (integer `50`), the system call will return `-EFAULT` (`-14`) in RAX.  (The kernel returns error codes on bad pointers to system calls, instead of delivering a SIGSEGV like it would if you deref in user-space).

See also [What are the return values of system calls in Assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38751614/what-are-the-return-values-of-system-calls-in-assembly)

Instead of writing code to check return values, in toy programs / experiments you should just run them under `strace ./a.out`. If you're writing your own `_start` without libc there won't be any other system calls during startup that you don't make yourself, so it's very easy to read the output, otherwise there are a bunch of startup system calls made by libc before your code.  [How should strace be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174942/how-should-strace-be-used)

Comment: (Without a red-zone, you could do `push rdi` / `mov rsi, rsp` / ... / syscall / `pop rcx` (or add rsp, 8) / `ret`.  For a 32-bit version with int 0x80, the pointer goes in EBX which is a call-preserved register so you'd want to push/pop it.  If args arrive in memory on the stack, you just need an LEA.  With a regparm convention you'd push the incoming register and EBX.)