# Problem with displaying stack values in a loop

Tags: assembly, x86-64, stack-memory

**rephrased the question**

Getting segmentation fault right after last printf after iterating and displaying stack values (2 iterations for simplicity purposes).
Just trying to display hex value on the stack in a loop. Tried aligning the stack with `sub rsp, 8` in steps (dumb me) meaning adding 8 bytes to the stack in an effort to come to aligned state, that didn't produce anything.

**another update**

Found that extending stack by 120 bytes does the job with aligning the stack.
Could someone please explain why it is 120..? I mean i have 3 CALLs and 3 PUSH'es before and in the Loop, each requiring 8 bytes additional stack (as far as my knowledge goes).

Code:

```
global _start
extern  printf

section .data
    ;format db "value at esp: %llx", 10, 0x00
    format db "%012llX", 10, 0x00
section .text
_start:
    mov rax,  0xa284ee5c7cde4bd7
    push   rax
    mov rax,  0x935add110510849a
    push   rax
    mov rax,  0x10b29a9dab697500
    push   rax
    mov rax,  0x200ce3eb0d96459a
    push   rax
    mov rax,  0xe64c30e305108462
    push   rax
    mov rax,  0x69cd355c7c3e0c51
    push   rax
    mov rax,  0x65659a2584a185d6
    push   rax
    mov rax,  0x69ff00506c6c5000
    push   rax
    mov rax,  0x3127e434aa505681
    push   rax
    mov rax,  0x6af2a5571e69ff48
    push   rax
    mov rax,  0x6d179aaff20709e6
    push   rax
    mov rax,  0x9ae3f152315bf1c9
    push   rax
    mov rax,  0x373ab4bb0900179a
    push   rax
    mov rax,  0x69751244059aa2a3
    push   rax
    ;---
    mov rbx,  0x2144d2144d2144d2 ;!!
    ;---
    xor rcx, rcx        ; initialize rcx to 0
    mov rcx, 2          ; initialize rcx to 14 loops
    mov r15, rsp        ; initialize the pointer to rsp right after pushing all of RAX
    call Loop
    call Exit           ; Exit the program

Loop:
    xor rax, rax
    mov r14, [r15]      ;have rax as temp holder of valu at rdx not to overwrite 
    ;xor r14, rbx       ;rdx while xoring at the next line
    push rcx
    push r14
    push r15
    call printMessage
    pop r15
    pop r14
    pop rcx
    
    add r15, 8          ;move up the stack
    loop Loop

printMessage:    
    mov rdi, format     ; set 1st argument (Print Format)
    mov rsi, r14        ; set 2nd argument (message)
    call printf         ; printf(outFormat, message)
    ret

Exit:
    mov rax, 60
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall
```

GDB on the last step before segmentation fault:

```
gef➤  r
Starting program: /home/kali/Desktop/assembly/exercise 1/Final/final1 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
69751244059AA2A3
373AB4BB0900179A

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
**0x00007ffff7e1db44 in __printf (format=0x403008 "%012llX\n") at ./stdio-common/printf.c:28
28      ./stdio-common/printf.c: No such file or directory.**
[ Legend: Modified register | Code | Heap | Stack | String ]
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── registers ────
$rax   : 0x11              
$rbx   : 0x2144d2144d2144d2
$rcx   : 0x0               
$rdx   : 0x0               
$rsp   : 0x00007fffffffdd48  →  0x0000000000000000
$rbp   : 0x0               
$rsi   : 0x373ab4bb0900179a
$rdi   : 0x0000000000403008  →  "%012llX\n"
$rip   : 0x00007ffff7e1db44  →  <printf+36> movaps XMMWORD PTR [rsp+0x50], xmm0
$r8    : 0x58              
$r9    : 0x0               
$r10   : 0x0               
$r11   : 0x202             
$r12   : 0x0000000000401020  →  <_start+0> movabs rax, 0xa284ee5c7cde4bd7
$r13   : 0x00007fffffffdea0  →  0x0000000000000001
$r14   : 0x373ab4bb0900179a
$r15   : 0x00007fffffffde40  →  0x9ae3f152315bf1c9
$eflags: [zero carry PARITY adjust sign trap INTERRUPT direction overflow RESUME virtualx86 identification]
$cs: 0x33 $ss: 0x2b $ds: 0x00 $es: 0x00 $fs: 0x00 $gs: 0x00 
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── stack ────
0x00007fffffffdd48│+0x0000: 0x0000000000000000   ← $rsp
0x00007fffffffdd50│+0x0008: 0x373ab4bb0900179a
0x00007fffffffdd58│+0x0010: 0x0000000000000000
0x00007fffffffdd60│+0x0018: 0x0000000000000001
0x00007fffffffdd68│+0x0020: 0x0000000000000400
0x00007fffffffdd70│+0x0028: 0x373ab4bb0900179a
0x00007fffffffdd78│+0x0030: 0x0000000000000000
0x00007fffffffdd80│+0x0038: 0x0000000000000000
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── code:x86:64 ────
   0x7ffff7e1db3b <printf+27>      mov    QWORD PTR [rsp+0x48], r9
   0x7ffff7e1db40 <printf+32>      test   al, al
   0x7ffff7e1db42 <printf+34>      je     0x7ffff7e1db7b <__printf+91>
 → 0x7ffff7e1db44 <printf+36>      movaps XMMWORD PTR [rsp+0x50], xmm0
   0x7ffff7e1db49 <printf+41>      movaps XMMWORD PTR [rsp+0x60], xmm1
   0x7ffff7e1db4e <printf+46>      movaps XMMWORD PTR [rsp+0x70], xmm2
   0x7ffff7e1db53 <printf+51>      movaps XMMWORD PTR [rsp+0x80], xmm3
   0x7ffff7e1db5b <printf+59>      movaps XMMWORD PTR [rsp+0x90], xmm4
   0x7ffff7e1db63 <printf+67>      movaps XMMWORD PTR [rsp+0xa0], xmm5
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── threads ────
[#0] Id 1, Name: "final1", stopped 0x7ffff7e1db44 in __printf (), reason: SIGSEGV
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── trace ────
[#0] 0x7ffff7e1db44 → __printf(format=0x403008 "%012llX\n")
[#1] 0x401106 → printMessage()
[#2] 0x4010d4 → _start()
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
gef➤  
gef➤  si

Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
The program no longer exists.
```

Comment: `mov rsi, r9 ; rsi: pointer to message` except of course `r9` is not a pointer, it's a value. Also it's 8 bytes not 20.

Comment: @Jester, 8 vs 20 my overlook, fixed. rsi should point to the display values... sorry, should i do: lea rsi, [r9] instead... ?

Comment: No, you can't point to a register. You need to put the value into memory and pass its address.

Comment: Aside: why not just have those values in an array?

Comment: would:
push r9
mov rsi, rsp
pop r9

be a really screwed up solution? Just tried it, it works, thank you.

Also how to modify syscall's stout format if there is a way? I wanted to display hex, but getting ascii: q��HP�1HHS!D�

Comment: @500-InternalServerError, I don't know yet how to operate arrays in assembly..:)

Comment: Pushing it to the stack is fine. No, the `write` system call does not support formatting. If you want hex you need to convert yourself.

Comment: If you want hex, see [How to convert a binary integer number to a hex string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53823756)

Comment: @T-series: oh. okay - fair enough.

Comment: `push r9` /  `mov rsi, rsp` / `pop r9` will leave the value below RSP, where it will be overwritten by the next `call`.  But it's fine in a leaf function, although of course `lea rsi, [rsp-8]` / `mov [rsi], r9` would be more efficient and simpler.  (And yes, putting stuff below RSP is safe since the x86-64 System V ABI has a red-zone.  See also [Writing a putchar in Assembly for x86\_64 with 64 bit Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50681077) which shows an example of this.)

Comment: Also, your loop would be simpler if you used a register other than RCX as the loop counter.  e.g. you could be doing `dec ebx`  `jnz Loop`.  The `loop` instruction itself is slow; it's just a code-size optimization for when it's convenient to have a counter in RCX.  (Or when you need to loop without clobbering FLAGS, but again, [only efficient on AMD not Intel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35742570/why-is-the-loop-instruction-slow-couldnt-intel-have-implemented-it-efficiently)).

Comment: Thank you for all the help.
Also wondering why am i getting segmentation fault with printf in printMessage function?

    `mov rdi, format   
    mov rsi, r9
    sub rsp, 8
    call printf `

Comment: Check the crashing instruction in the debugger Chances are, the stack is misaligned. Try without the `sub rsp, 8`.

Comment: @Jester, was just GDB'ing and found that r8 and r9 are being overwritten from printf call.

Comment: Yeah well that's normal as per calling convention. But then the crash should be in your code :)

Comment: Your `Loop` is falling through into `printMessage` because it's missing a `ret`. For stack alignment to 16 bytes you only need either 0 or 8 bytes if `rsp` is at least 8 bytes aligned. That should be in `printMessage` and of course has to be balanced.