# Moving from friendly UI (Emu8086) to real x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I am a expert of the emu8086 emulator assembly (this is what we are taught in university) but obviously the emu8086 emulator is NOT real assembly language and im trying to learn the x86 Assembly language.

I am using [this online compiler](https://onecompiler.com/assembly/3zu96dtcq) as my learning tool.

I have found the system calls for a x86 microproccessor:

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/docs/+/master/constants/syscalls.md#x86-32_bit

and I will keep it open since I am still a newbie.

From the `emu8086` im familiar with general and special use registers and altho the names are a bit different I can still remain on the path.

I am trying to print out  a 32-bit integer

I have noticed that for each value of the `eax` register , there is a different system call so we cant use `eax` to perform operations in there.

The `ebx` register needs to be set to 1 since my only output is 1 value.

From the Chromium OS Docs the value is set by the `ecx` register and the `edx` gives out the size of the operand of the `ecx` register.

I have written down this code:

```
section .data
    hello:     db 'Hello, World!',10    ; 'Hello, World!' plus a linefeed character
    helloLen:  equ $-hello             ; Length of the 'Hello world!' string

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov eax,4            
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,1
    mov edx,16
    
                         
    int 0x80
```

(Obviously im  not using any of the variables in the `.data` section)

I want to print out 1.I set `ecx` to 1 and `edx` to 16 since a integer has 16 bits.However nothing is printed out!What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `write` system call does not take integers. You need to pass a pointer to a buffer with the bytes (text) you want printed. PS: that site seems to be 64 bit. While it might work in some cases, you should not use 32 bit code.

Comment: which system call takes chars?How do I create a buffer?

Comment: the write syscall you are using has ecx marked as `const char *buf` that is "pointer to some chars"

Comment: yes ok but can we not print out 1 char at the time by referencing to its ASCII value?

Comment: Note the word `pointer` there. If you put it somewhere in memory first, sure. Note: the ascii value of '1' is not 1.

Comment: Also the length is counted in bytes not bits and the ascii code of `'1'` is not `1`.

Comment: @Jester so it's higher level assembly right? Assembly built on assembly.

Comment: Not sure what you mean.

Comment: I mean that some calls have code behind them, it's not direct translation of machine code.Like the "string.h"  library in C. C recognizes strings as array of chars but by using this library you turn on higher level of code to be run in a C program. Of course it is still C but with already existing libraries.

Comment: System calls go to the OS, which is of course more code already written.

Comment: Yeah you can't write down your own OS with it.

Comment: emu8086 *is* a real assembler (not a very good one) which uses the same syntax and directives as MASM/TASM.  The generated machine code can only (or is normally) run inside a simulator, not on a real CPU, though.  And the simulator simulates some aspects of an IBM-PC running DOS, like int 21h DOS calls (https://web.archive.org/web/20230702070006/http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html) and some int 10h / int 13h BIOS calls among others.  None of these APIs are available in 32 or 64-bit code under other OSes.

Comment: Most code that runs in EMU8086 would also run in DOSBox, or Bochs or QEMU booting FreeDOS.  (But real code that hooks interrupts like keyboard or timer won't work in emu8086 because it doesn't simulate interrupts.)  So again, EMU8086 is a real assembler that loosely simulates a real but obsolete system with an older version of the same ISA as x86-64.  In case that helps you understand what you learned.  386 and AMD64 added many new instructions that make things less painful than on 8086, e.g. `movsx edx, byte [esi]` / `imul edx, ecx` is a thing so you aren't forced to use [E]AX as much.

Comment: See [Writing a putchar in Assembly for x86\_64 with 64 bit Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50681077) for a 64-bit version.  Just store to the stack and pass `write` a pointer to stack memory.  Like `write(1, &local_var, 1)`.  Or for integers, you need to do int to string conversion like printf would.  See [How do I print an integer in Assembly Level Programming without printf from the c library? (itoa, integer to decimal ASCII string)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46301894) or a 32-bit version [Add 2 numbers and print the result using Assembly x86](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28524951)

Comment: You **can** of course write your OS in assembly. But you should not try that while already running an OS.

Comment: How can I write my OS on this assembly if the system calls are for Linux tho?

Comment: You can't do it on that site. You can do it on a real machine. You wouldn't use any system calls of course. You'd need to boot your code, talk to the hardware, write drivers and whatnot.

Comment: If you were writing an OS, it would set up a handler for `int 0x80` and `syscall` so user-space could make system-calls *into your OS code*.  Your OS would need drivers to talk to the actual hardware to implement those system calls.  For code running under Linux, see [What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46087731) for some details about what kernel code runs when you execute `int 0x80`.

Comment: "I am a expert of the emu8086 emulator assembly" -- I do not think the guys who wrote the emu8086 emulator would call themselves experts in emu8086 emulator assembly.

Comment: @MikeNakis how figure?

Comment: It is called "modesty". You should look it up.

Comment: Lmao what you say is like this:Linus Torvals is not a expert on Linux even tho he wrote down the very first version of it.

Answer (score 1):

From the link you provided the "write" syscall name requires these parameters:

- `ebx`->`unsigned int fd`
- `ecx`->`buffer`
- `edx`->`count`

The problem is the `buffer` parameter. You moved the `buffer` to 1 and `count` to 16 but `char*` have a size of 4 (x86) and 8 (x64), also `count` must be the length of string including LF.

You should have a pointer, e.g. `hello` and exiting normally, if not it will run infinitely.

Code:

```
section .data
    hello:     db '1',10
    helloLen:  equ $ - hello

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov eax,4            ; The system call for write (sys_write)
    mov ebx,1            ; File descriptor 1 - standard output
    mov ecx,hello        ; Put the offset of hello in ecx
    mov edx,helloLen     ; helloLen is a constant, so we don't need to say
                         ;  mov edx,[helloLen] to get it's actual value
    int 80h              ; Call the kernel
    mov eax,1            ; The system call for exit (sys_exit)
    mov ebx,0            ; Exit with return "code" of 0 (no error)
    int 80h;
```

Comment: Why is there no feedback on this answer, @Root? Is it not good?