# Define inline bytes to register in NASM; put db string in .data and get a pointer to it all with one source line?

Tags: assembly, x86, macros, byte, nasm

Is there any way of passing bytes this way?

```
mov ecx, byte ["mybytes",0xa,0]
```

instead of:

```
section .data
    mybytes db "mybytes",0xa,0

section .text
    global main

main:
    mov ecx, mybytes
```

Comment: You can make a macro if you wish, with a slightly different syntax.

Comment: @Jester unfortunately i could not find any way of doing that

Comment: NASM `%define` macros can't do the job since they can't expand to multiple source lines.  You could make a `%macro` that you use like `string_to_register  ecx, "mybytes", 0xa, 0` which takes a destination as the first parameter, with the rest becoming operands for a `db` directive.  (Use `[section .rodata]` and `__?SECT?__` to put data in another section and then switch back to the original, as shown in the example macro in https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc7.html#section-7.3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [an example from the NASM manual](https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc7.html#section-7.3), I have created a perfect macro:

```
%macro print 1+
        [section .rodata]        ; switch sections without updating the macro
                %%data db %1          ; expand all the macro args
                %%dataLen equ $- %%data
               ; db 0    ; optional 0 terminator outside the calculated length
                         ; only useful if you need an implicit-length C string 
        __?SECT?__               ; switch back to the user's  section
                mov eax, 4
                mov ebx, 1
                mov ecx, %%data
                mov edx, %%dataLen
                int 0x80
%endmacro
```

and now i can simply `print "string"` and it works!

The `1+` number of params allows it to be used like `print "string", 0xa` to include a newline.

---

To just put a pointer in a register, you could write a macro like

```
%macro string_ptr 2+
        [section .rodata]
                %%data db %2
               ; db 0    ; optional 0 terminator baked into the macro
        __?SECT?__
                mov %1, %%data   ; or lea %1, [rel %%data]  for 64-bit
%endmacro

; use like this:
  string_ptr  ecx, "hello", 0xa, "world", 0
  push ecx
  call puts
```

A fancier macro might allow `push %%data` to avoid wasting instructions getting it into a register first, for 32-bit stack-arg calling conventions.  Or a separate macro that pushes, instead of making one flexible but complex macro.

Comment: Your macro prints a literal `0` byte at the end of your string (`write` takes a pointer and length.  It doesn't care if the final byte is a `0` or not, it outputs what it's told: it works on binary data.)  You can see this with `strace ./foo` or `./foo | hexdump -C`.  And it doesn't allow multiple args, like `"string", 0xa` so you can't print a newline even if you wanted one.  To fix that, `%macro print 1+` to allow optional extra macro args that expand as part of `%1`, as shown in the NASM manual's example: https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc7.html#section-7.3

Comment: @PeterCordes it prints a literal `0` because if I use the print twice with different content, it prints twice the same thing. That was the approach i found to correct this error. And thanks for the `1+` tip, now I am wondering how can I print the content of a register. Do you know? So I can update the answer.

Comment: You mean print an ASCII string representation of the number?  [How do I print an integer in Assembly Level Programming without printf from the c library? (itoa, integer to decimal ASCII string)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46301894) or [How to convert a binary integer number to a hex string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53823756) .  Or [Writing a putchar in Assembly for x86\_64 with 64 bit Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50681077) if you want to dump one or more bytes directly to stdout.

Comment: Re: printing the same thing twice: IDK what you're doing wrong, but that's not what I'd expect and not what happens for me.  https://godbolt.org/z/TfY4EPs85 shows it working correctly the way I suggested.