# How to push number on stack and print in assembly NASM?

Tags: assembly, stack, x86-64, nasm, system-calls

My code is supposed to separate the digits of the random number 625, push them onto the stack, and then print them by popping them from the stack. I have tried various ways to solve this, but it seems I am making a mistake somewhere. Can someone help?

```
section .data
    buffer db 3 dup(0)       ; Reserve space for 3 digits + null terminator
    message db "Hello, World!", 0

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov rax, 625            ; Load the number 625 into register rax
    mov rcx, 10             ; Divide by 10, using rcx as the divisor

convert_loop:
    xor rdx, rdx            ; Set rdx to zero for division
    div rcx                 ; Divide rax by rcx, quotient in rax, remainder in rdx
    add dl, '0'             ; Convert the remainder to ASCII character
    push rdx                ; Push the character onto the stack

    test rax, rax           ; Check if rax is zero (end of the loop)
    jnz convert_loop        ; If not, repeat the loop

    ; Pop characters from the stack and print them
    mov eax, 1              ; Syscall for writing
    mov ebx, 1              ; File descriptor for stdout

    pop rdi                 ; Pop the first digit from the stack to rdi
    mov [buffer], rdi      ; Store the first digit in the buffer
    mov edx, 1              ; Number of bytes to write (first digit)
    syscall                 ; Invoke the syscall

    pop rdi                 ; Pop the second digit from the stack to rdi
    mov [buffer+1], rdi    ; Store the second digit in the buffer
    mov edx, 1              ; Number of bytes to write (second digit)
    syscall                 ; Invoke the syscall

    pop rdi                 ; Pop the third digit from the stack to rdi
    mov [buffer+2], rdi    ; Store the third digit in the buffer
    mov edx, 1              ; Number of bytes to write (third digit)
    syscall                 ; Invoke the syscall

    ; Print the message "Hello, World!"
    mov eax, 4              ; Syscall for writing
    mov ebx, 1              ; File descriptor for stdout
    mov edx, 13             ; Length of the message
    mov ecx, message        ; Address of the message
    syscall                 ; Invoke the syscall

    ; End of the program
    mov eax, 60             ; Syscall for program exit
    xor edi, edi            ; Exit status
    syscall
```

Is there an easier way to do this, but using push and pop? I've also tried to print the sentence using the stack, but it's not working.

section .data
newline db ' ', 10
number dd 625
section .text
global _start
print:
push rax
push rbx
mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
int 0x80
pop rbx
pop rax
ret
_start:
mov eax, [number]
mov rcx, 3
loop:
mov ebx, 10
xor edx, edx
div ebx
add dl, '0'
push rdx
dec rcx
cmp rcx, 0
jne loop
pop rax
mov ebx, 1
mov rcx, rax
mov edx, 1
call print
mov edx, 2
mov rcx, newline
call print
pop rax
mov rcx, rax
call print
mov edx, 2
mov rcx, newline
call print
pop rax
mov rcx, rax
call print
mov eax, 1
xor ebx, ebx
int 0x80

I tried something like this now, but it still doesn't print anything.

Comment: Yes, the easier way is to generate ASCII digits into a buffer in the first place, starting from the end (where you put the least significant digit which you get first).  Then make *one* `write` system call to output all the digits, much more efficient.  [How do I print an integer in Assembly Level Programming without printf from the c library? (itoa, integer to decimal ASCII string)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46301894)

Comment: Your code correctly uses RAX=1 (`__NR_write` from unistd_64.h) for the digits, but later uses RAX=4 (the 32-bit call number, `__NR_write` from unistd_32.h) when it tries to write the Hello World message.  And you put the args in EBX, ECX, and EDX, like for `int 0x80`, but you used `syscall`.  Use the 64-bit system-call calling convention in 64-bit code.  ([What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46087730))

Comment: Also, your digit-printing code uses the `write()` return values (in RAX) as the system-call number for the next system call.  If you were passing the correct file descriptor (in RDI), it would return `1` and actually work, but that's evil.  Use `strace` to see what you're actually passing: `write(c, &c, 1)` where `c` is the character value that you're also passing as the file descriptor.  (An integer like 0x31 (aka `'1'`) will make `write` return `-EBADF`, a small negative integer, and leaving that in RAX will make later `syscall`s return `-ENOSYS` from an invalid call number.)

Comment: Thank you for the response, I really appreciate it. However, you see, I have just started learning assembly, and I'm having difficulty figuring out how to correct this. Most of these terms are unfamiliar to me. Do you have a simple example code where a number is pushed onto the stack, printed, and then popped off the stack? Gratefully in advance.

Comment: Oh, I thought you were asking if there was an easier way than push/pop.  (Which there is.)  Now I see you meant if there's an easier way that does still use push/pop.  IDK why you want that, it's inefficient and requires an extra counter or like you're doing here, fully unrolling a fixed number of digit iterations.  Your code would work if you used the right registers for args to `syscall`: fd=EDI, pointer=RSI, length=RDX, and call number (write=`1`) in RAX, as described in the duplicate about syscall calling conventions.

Comment: [Writing a putchar in Assembly for x86\_64 with 64 bit Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50681077) shows how to use `syscall` to `write` a single character at a time, if you really want to do that.  With the bytes already on the stack, you could just `mov rsi, rsp`.

Comment: My professor at the university assigned us a couple of tasks for practicing push and pop. For some reason, they require us to learn the application of push and pop, using the stack itself. Most of the tasks involve a subtask of placing something on the stack and printing it. Tasks like these often appear on tests, so I'm trying to understand this. :)

Comment: I tried to write the code a bit differently now, there are no errors, but it still doesn't print anything.

Comment: Use `strace` to see what system calls your code makes (if your system is new enough for strace to work on int 0x80 in 64-bit code). The 32-bit `int 0x80` interface only works with 32-bit pointers, so you can't use it to print stack space in a 64-bit program. (RSP is outside the low 4GiB). See [What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46087730) and [Writing a putchar in Assembly for x86\_64 with 64 bit Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50681077) for details on why it doesn't work, and how to use `syscall` to make 64-bit `write` calls.

Comment: Also, it looks like you're putting values in RCX, not pointers.  `write(int fd, void *buf, size_t len)` needs a pointer to a character in memory.  The assembly `putchar` Q&A covers that, too.